# distribute R pop-up figures on different parts of the screen

Tags: r, graphics

If I have multiple pop-up figures in R initiated with `window()`. However, they are all plotted in the same spot, masking each other. Is there a way to automatically space them out on the screen(s). What I am looking for is an R implementation of this Matlab function: https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37176-distribute-figures.
I am aware of the `par(mfrow)` and the `layout()` options for multipanel figures but they are not what I am looking for.

Comment: Where are you finding the `window` function?  The one in base R doesn't have anything to do with graphics.  If you meant `windows`, then use the `xpos` and `ypos` arguments to set the position.

Answer (score 0):

The function name is `windows`, not `window`.  (It is only available in MS Windows, not other platforms.)  It has arguments `xpos` and `ypos` that set the position.  If you want your windows in random positions, do something like this:

```
windows(xpos = -300*runif(1), ypos = 200*runif(1))
```

(The negative value for `xpos` measures from the right side of the screen.)

If the graphics windows already exist, you can use `arrangeWindows()` to distribute them on your screen.  (Again, only in MS Windows.)